# 'Unexpected string' when running karma with webpack/babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, karma-runner, babeljs

I'm trying to run karma using webpack to preprocess code with babel that can then be tested with mocha. However whenever I run it I get errors.

*spec/tests.spec.js:*

```
import 'chai/register-expect';
```

*karma.conf.js:*

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

const tests = './spec/**/*.spec.js'

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    singleRun: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    frameworks: ['mocha'],
    files: [
      tests
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      tests: ['webpack'],
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
  })
}
```

*webpack.config.js:*

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env', {
            'modules': false
          }]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run karma I get the following output:

> 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string\nat http://localhost:9876/base/spec/tests.spec.js?af68737606dd067ef21aa6efadfc004fb1d05454:1:8\n

Which corresponds to the `import` line.

If I remove all es6 code from the test, then it runs successfully, implying that webpack/babel isn't being invoked properly.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was nothing to do with any of the tools, and turned out to be a JS gotcha.

In karma.conf.js I was doing:

```
const tests = './spec/**/*.spec.js'
...
    preprocessors: {
      tests: ['webpack'],
    }
```

The problem here is that `tests` as an object key translates to the string `"tests"`.

The solution was to use:

```
preprocessors: {
  [tests]: ['webpack'],
}
```

So that `tests` gets expanded properly to the variable value.